# $message->embed cannot read the path of an image

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to embed a logo to be displayed on the email I'm sending. Despite the path being correct and the file existing in the specified directory (as I'm using it in other views), the email view cannot read it for some reason.

Up in the email I'm linking a font, which actually works the following way:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: "ValueSansPro-Regular";
            src: url("/edu/fonts-bit/ValueSansPro-Regular.ttf");
        }
```

But when I'm trying to embed the logo like this

`src="{{ $message->embed('/img/logo.svg') }}"`

I get the following error: `Path "/img/logo.svg" is not readable.`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is your file located in the /public/img directory? If so, try `src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . '/img/logo.svg') }}"`. Looks like `embed` needs to be a full URL.

Comment: @EdenDowling-Mitchell Thank you for the answer, but the logo still does not display, and I got an attachment in the email.